# Undefinable generic class parameters

Tags: typescript, class, generics, parameters

Below I have a class that has generic class parameters I'd like this to be undefinable but when they are defined I'd like the public properties to be non-nullable, How can I get this code below to pass typechecking and maintain the functionality I'm looking for?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wObBgEQIYzAByMAFnALxwBmArsgjAJYoAUAJgFxzK0C2AI2BQAlHADeAWABQcOE2pwOcAHxwAzHABkWuOzgAeOACYAjGKjZaUZHADkZOwG4Zc1AHcmMBOWUBSOFMABjEpWTlEPFRgQO44SxhrWwAidGSXcLkEKJjjOISkuGTkdnTXCOzojXyrGyKoUoyIvWBqPFoAGxhuArrksjLwgF8ZEekZBA6o1DgAYTwO4BK8KHxCA3KcAEEATThQQhKZ3kFhOAAfOHp2VqZkYHYAGnKiABUACX2QQ-YZ9Cg7hgLlcSrd7k9ygBZACSABkvj9jvwhFBgdcwQ8ZGoDktfnA1jEwlkUP9aIxoKxynIwLQBB0mAg9ARgNwCc9MnAaXSGUyAJ6s3aUEE3ah3B7s5pc+mM5BkbhvT5UdGi8ESiJSnl8JgdenRJBHbgw+FK0Eq8XlUJUuCoWhgYQcZkicpjORYeAAEnYeF5SktHP16D5QrITFQADo3QTWE6Ob1bPd3HMFriVlGQ6hHnzM+mw7LSDG5C64G64O6876JFaA-Boh1FFQc57vVWSfBy1RI8ySKRWLXqGGvbyCxE4zxgIn5otlqtmb3gHXM32B97M3nh0WS+6tTrQ8B9Xjo5X-a24Nvd-uZg3SKGwwA3Ba0YAAeWo0ato4TSanXpnhFY6eza9w0HQCbzzTMzz1FBfnXUYZAmE99CoT9JxTX9gFYT8oxEGMZHYMMm15ZdeSAA)

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'NTH'.
> 'undefined' is assignable to the constraint of type 'NTH', but 'NTH' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | undefined'.

[image]

```
class CalendarDate<
  DAY extends number | undefined,
  NTH extends string | undefined,
  MIL extends number | undefined
> extends Date {
  constructor(
    public date: Date,
    public day: DAY = undefined,
    public nth: NTH = undefined,
    public milliseconds: MIL = undefined,
  ) {
    super(date)
  }
  get $day () {
    const day = this.getDate()
    return new CalendarDate(this, day, this.nth)
  }
  get $nth () {
    const self = this.$day
    const nth = getDateNth(self.day)
    return new CalendarDate(self, self.day, nth)
  }
  get $milliseconds () {
    const miliseconds = this.valueOf()
    return new CalendarDate(this, this.day, this.nth, miliseconds)
  }
}

const d = new CalendarDate(new Date())

d.$day.day
```

Comment: Why is this class even generic in the first place? I don't quite understand what the generics are for.

Comment: You should make the generic parameters the ones that get a default: https://tsplay.dev/wXqL1N

Comment: @caTS the generics are meant to "hydrate" the parameter values in the class signature when they are provided. your example doesn't work to limit the type of the parameters when they are provided, they can still be undefined, the generic doesn't work.

Comment: So... [this](https://tsplay.dev/w179Gm)? I don't understand what you are expecting of the type system here.

Comment: It would be *extremely* beneficial if you included more example uses and the expected errors/behaviors. Currently it feels like stabbing in the dark, but if you have some expectations of what should be happening, it's a lot easier to appeal to the type system.

Comment: This looks like [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49158#issuecomment-1130070548) but the workaround with overloads doesn't easily work for generic class constructors.  The options I see are either [require all arguments](https://tsplay.dev/w2zo8w), or [use a static helper](https://tsplay.dev/NB56bw), or [assert that the class constructor has generic overloads](https://tsplay.dev/mAr0XW).  Do any of those work for you? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)